# slick.js class of slide in navigation

Tags: css, slick.js

I'm using slick.js for my carousel.

I'm adding a custom class to every slide in a `foreach` loop.

Do you think I can target the class of the slide in the navigation `li`?

For example, if one slide has `class='test'` and the second slide has `class='test2'`, in the navigation I want the `li` of the first slide to have `class='test'` and the `li` of the second slide to have `class='test2'` so that I can customize the CSS for the navigation for each slide.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you asking if you can target `.test` or `.test2`? Or are you asking if you can a class to each `li`?

Comment: I want to add a class to each li and if possible it would be the class of the slide of that li.  Sorry if its not very clear

Comment: There is a `data-slick-index` that is added to each slide, an `id` of `slick-slide#` on each slide, as well as a `slick-active` class for the current slide. You could target any one of those in your css.

Comment: Ok thanks for  the help ill try that. Im able to style the nav li with the slick-active but i need the slick-active to have different style for each slide.

Comment: `#slick-slide00 .slick-active {...}` - `#slick-slide01 .slick-active {...}` - `#slick-slide02 .slick-active {...}` ...

Comment: Nice thank you very much!!